# Calling servcie constructor in component class

Tags: angular, service, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I have the following code in service

```
  constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private firestore: AngularFirestore,

    ){
        this.user = afAuth.authState;
        this.LoggedInUserList = firestore.collection(this.dbPath);
        this.user.subscribe(res =>{
            this.loggedInUserKey = res.uid;
            this.userDetails$ = this.LoggedInUserList.doc(res.uid);
        })
    }
```

And I am accessing the value in each component like below

```
 constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
   ) {

  }
  ngOnInit()
  {

    this.authService.userDetails$.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });

  }
```

Until the page is not refreshed it is fine, but when I do a refresh of the page the userdetails$ became undefined.

I am new in angular Could you please help

Note: I was previously using localstorage, But I don't want to use this.
As I am storing userdetails in firestore and corresponding key to fetch user details is in afAuth.authState, So I have all details with me, no need to user local storage.

**Update:** 
The happening behind is in component, authService: AuthService is calling service constructor but before completing the constructor 
below code executed and that point of time the assignment to userdetails$ is not finished

```
 this.authService.userDetails$.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes this will happen because it a js variable and on refresh it will set to undefined.

Use SessionStorage or localStorage or cookies to store your data.

When you hit refresh copy your data in any of the above storage and on init copy it back into your variable.
Check below example. Replace the sessionStorage to localStorage to store data in localStorage.

**In AppComponent**

```
    ngOnInit() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("user")) {
      this.data.changeUser(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
    }
      }
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
      unloadNotification($event: any) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("user", this.getUser());
      }
```

Let me know if you have any futher doubts..

**Option 2**

put the below code in on function and call this in your service constructor as well as in your component on oninit function. Should work

```
this.user = afAuth.authState;
        this.LoggedInUserList = firestore.collection(this.dbPath);
        this.user.subscribe(res =>{
            this.loggedInUserKey = res.uid;
            this.userDetails$ = this.LoggedInUserList.doc(res.uid);
        })
```

Comment: Nope I have moved from session or local storage to firstore, I am storing all details in firestore,

Comment: Check i have added option 2 in my answer.